# Recursively make get request

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am now trying to recursively traverse JSON through get request, it can make get request for the entrylevel json but the recursion process does not actually work. I used firebase for hosting, and I get the error with status code 400, I will post my code below, thanks for help in advance!

The firebase log:

7:30:02.482 PM
outlined_flag
QueryPos
Function execution took 4597 ms, finished with status code: 400

7:30:02.481 PM
warning 
QueryPos
Wed, 23 Aug 2017 02:30:02 GMT actions-on-google:error undefined

FYI, get_request_handler deals with the get request without any problem.

```
function traverse_doc(assistant, doc_name, input_json, output){
    for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(input_json['data']).length; i++){
        if (input_json['data'][i]['name'] == doc_name)
            return;
        if (input_json['data'][i]['props'].hasOwnProperty('HasChildren') == true){
            let sub_dir_url = input_json['data'][i]['self'];
            get_request_handler(assistant, sub_dir_url, function(callback){
                traverse_doc(assistant, doc_name, JSON.parse(callback), output);
            });
        }else{
            output = output + input_json['data'][i]['name'] + '.';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 400 code is for bad request. Have you checked the path you are using? Also, please share the logs so it will be more clear what is going on. Thanks.

Comment: Hi it seems like the problem is firebase timeout is triggered during the recursion. The maximum time is 60,000ms. I've make the JSON structure smaller and it works now.